# The pics taken from my canon 18-135 mm zoom lens are blurred

Tags: lens, canon, camera

[image: taken by zooming in]When ever I take photos in my canon lens during zoomed out they are of good quality and sharp but when ever I take photos that are far or somewhat near to me i find them to be blurred and lack of sharpness even in live video I found the same what may be the reason can anyone suggest me

Comment: Please add some sample photos from your lens, including the settings used for each - thanks.

Comment: I have shared one pic plz check

Comment: Could you please include the settings used (focal length, shutter speed, aperture and ISO)? At the moment, that could well be shake from having much too long an exposure.

Comment: F/5.6, 1/500, iso 640, 135mm, no flash used

Answer (score 1):

Was it windy? The photo shows motion blur, but trying to correct one area doesn't fix it all, so there's the chance it was all moving at different speeds in different directions.

Before…
[image]

After…
[image]

The correction isn't perfect, but that it works at all indicates motion blur rather than purely out of focus.

We need more detail on the shot you posted - Aperture, shutter speed, iso, etc, whether the lens has Image Stabilisation.
You could probably sacrifice ISO to gain a shorter shutter speed, though overall it's a tad over-exposed anyway.

Comment: F/5.6, 1/500, iso 640, 135mm, no flash used

Comment: Actually recently I gave my camera for cleaning does it effect that

Comment: Run a few test shots. Use something with clear delineation, eg the face of a building so you can check such as bricks, windows & door edges for blur. Test at 1/500 & also faster. The building, of course, won't move, so it will be easier to see what's going on. if you're still seeing the same issue, take it back to the repair shop for them to check it.